# String pointer in C prints weird symbol

Tags: c, string, pointers, ascii

I was having some difficulties when trying to print out the string pointer after dynamically insert a character at the front of char array.

The parameter *str is a dynamic char array from my main whereas the input is a single character which should append to the first element of the dynamic array after executing the insert().

```
int main(){ 
//code snippet. I removed other part to keep the question short
printf("How many characters do you want to input: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
str = malloc(n + 1);
printf("Input the string class: ");
scanf("%s", str);

//switch statement
case '1':
    printf("What is the character you want to insert: ");
    scanf(" %c", &input);
    insert(&str, input);
    break;
}
return 0;
}

void insert(char *str, char input) {
    char *new_str;
    int i, len = strlen(str);

    new_str = malloc(len + 1);
    new_str[0] = input;
    strncpy(&new_str[1], str, len - 1);
    new_str[len] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%c", new_str[i]);
    }
}
```

When I tried to loop thru the new_str and print out the string array, it gives me weird symbols and I have no idea what are they. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The expected output as below:

```
How many characters do you want to input: 5
Input the string:datas
The string is: datas
Do you want to 1-insert or 2-remove or 3-quit?: 1
What is the character you want to insert: a
Resulting string: adata
```

The output I am getting:

[image]

Comment: `strlen()` does not count the terminating null.

Comment: So how should I modify it? Change the second condition in for loop to new_str[i] != '\0' ?

Comment: maybe `malloc(len + 2)`?

Comment: No need to use `strncpy` either (badly). Use `strcpy`.

Comment: strncpy() is a terrible function, it does **not** do what most people think at first. Better not use it, or read the manual first. before deciding not to use it.

Comment: Nope, both does not works.

Comment: Step though the code, line by line, in a debugger. And make sure that the arguments you pass are valid to begin with.

Comment: As the string got one character longer, the for loop must go until `i<= len`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think it's the problem with either len +2, strncpy to strcpy or i <= len. None of them fixed it :(

Comment: @JoachimPileborg just noticed. removed.

Comment: What is your input to this function, and what output do you get?

Comment: The input is a char which append to the first element of dynamic char array. The output that I get is some weird symbols. I can't really tell what are they.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What are the exact values of the parameters (print them before calling the function), and what is the exact output?

Comment: I edited my question already. Sorry for the lack of info. I did printed out the input before calling the function and it was correct.

Comment: Remove the `&` in `insert(&str, input);`

Comment: @4566976 It works. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Because `&str` is the address of the pointer to the string, not the string itself.

Comment: Alright I see I see. Thanks a lot for pointing out!

Answer (score 3):

Alternative version, avoiding any string copy functions. (Since, alter the strlen() you already *know* the string length to copy, you don't *need* any more string functions)

```
char * insert_a_character(char * str, char ch)
{
char * new;
size_t len;

if (!str) return NULL;
len = strlen(str);

new = malloc (1+len+1);
if (!new) retun NULL;

new[0] = ch;
memcpy(new+1, str, len);
new[len+1] = 0;

return new;
}
```

Comment: other than using a C++ keyword 'new' for a variable name, this is an excellent answer

Comment: That was on purpose. C and C++ are different languages. Confusing them leads to even larger problems.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the caller will `free` if required for `orig`

```
char * insert(char *orig, char input) {
   char * new_str = malloc(strlen(orig) + 2); // An extra one for null
   strcpy(new_str + 1, orig);
   new_str[0] = input;
   printf("%s", new_str); // To print it out
   return new_str; // The caller needs to free this;
}
```

That should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still print out the weird symbols

Comment: What is weird? and what is input?. What is original? The problem is up the chain

Comment: ... Tried using the debugger?

Comment: Besides where is `main`

Comment: I will return the favour when required

Answer (score 1):

Assembling all comments:

```
void insert(char *str, char input) {
    char *new_str;
    int i, len = strlen(str);

    new_str = malloc(len + 2);
    new_str[0] = input;
    strcpy(new_str+1, str);
    new_str[len+1] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        printf("%c", new_str[i]);
    }
}
```

Of course you still need to do something with the new string, such as returning it or freeing it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the weird symbol still prints out.

Comment: Then the weird symbol is `input`. Take a debugger and inspect it. I tested it and it works fine/

Comment: But when I commented out the rests of the code and try to print input from the insert(), it is print the user input passed from main().

Comment: When calling the function, you must call it as: `insert(str, input);' so without the `&`.